# How do I detect if the app is written in Kotlin, given an APK file?

Tags: android, kotlin, apk, decompiling

I have multiple APK files, and I would like to know if they were created with Kotlin. Some unique strings, imports? 
As I understand, looking only by the word 'kotlin' can give me some false results. 
Thanks!

Comment: you can't detect

Comment: You could do reverse engineering with this [Tool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)

Comment: Are you doing this by hand or writing an automated tool? I think automating it will boil down to a bag of heuristic tricks, and still be unreliable.

Comment: For now, I just need to detect if it was written in kotlin(partly or whole). I have apktool, jeb and dex2jar. Thanks!

Comment: Is the [SourceFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.10) attribute preserved across the round-trip conversion to dex and back?  If so, presumably the value would be a file name with a `.kt` extension.  I wouldn't rely solely on that, as it's an _optional_ attribute anyway, but you could combine it with @voddan's suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin compiler saves its metadata about every Kotlin class into a runtime annotation `@kotlin.Metadata` which should be preserved into APK. So to detect Kotlin classes all you need to do is to detect this annotation.

Comment: What do you think if I just will search for the string "kotlin.Metadata"? Would it be sufficient?

Comment: You could have false positives in case someone, for any reason, puts that string into their Java application. But on the other side, they could also create an annotation called `kotlin.Metadata` I guess, so you could get false positives, also with that strategy. In my opinion it's unlikely for someone to put that string into their application, so I think it could be a good approximation

Comment: @ElenaRoot what's wrong with loading the class and checking if it is annotated with this annotation via reflection?

Comment: Alternatively, you can do that manually by using a bytecode viewer and again, checking for the annotation

Comment: @voddan I checked on 100 apks existence of "kotlin/Metadata" and only half of them contain this string.